# Please help me understand the meaning of media attribute in HTML5

Tags: html

I have started learning HTML5 from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/). I am stuck here with the **media attribute** in `<a>` tag. Can anyone tell me does it mean that the site the link points to is developed for a special device or something else? Also wanted to ask if it could still be visited by any device. 
Thank you

Comment: W3Schools has its use, but you'll be [much better off](http://w3fools.com) if it is not your primary resource. Try the [Mozilla Dev Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) instead.

Comment: @Matt: Thank you. Actually I wanted to be very good in HTML5 so I thought that W3school would be great. I will follow your link :)

Comment: Another non-sucky HTML5 resource: [HTML5 Doctor](http://html5doctor.com/).

Comment: Thankyou all of you for helping.I like HtmlDog. I have started learning from it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you realize, but w3schools is not connected at all with w3.

the media attribute describes what type of format the link is. For example, if the link is going to a mobile optimized site, use media="handheld".